# How to get multiple ringtones from a ringtone folder in file manager?

Tags: android

I have attached some code to get single ringtone in file manager. I have to get multiple ringtones from a ringtone folder in file manager.

```
public void ringtone(){

    Log.i("TEST", "inside the ringtone");
    String filepath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath();
    Log.i("FilePath", filepath);
    filepath = filepath + "/ringtone";
    final MediaMetadataRetriever retriever = new MediaMetadataRetriever();
    retriever.setDataSource(filepath);
    final String title = new File(filepath).getName();
    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
    values.put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.DATA, title);
    values.put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.TITLE, "song");
    values.put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.SIZE, "450kb");
    values.put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.MIME_TYPE, "audio/mp3");
    values.put(MediaStore.Audio.Media.IS_RINGTONE, true);
    values.put(MediaStore.Audio.Media.IS_NOTIFICATION, false);
    values.put(MediaStore.Audio.Media.IS_ALARM, false);
    values.put(MediaStore.Audio.Media.IS_MUSIC, false);

    //Insert it into the database
    Uri uri = MediaStore.Audio.Media.getContentUriForPath(title);
    Log.i("uri", "" + uri);
    getContentResolver().delete(uri, MediaStore.MediaColumns.DATA + "=\"" + title + "\"", null);
    Uri newUri = getApplicationContext().getContentResolver().insert(uri, values);
    //Log.i("URI",""+newUri);
    RingtoneManager.setActualDefaultRingtoneUri(getApplicationContext(), RingtoneManager.TYPE_RINGTONE, newUri);
}
}
```